# Calculate GPA and echo only records above 3.75 or 4.0

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably a sloppy way of doing this but I will share my method to calculate GPA's.

I started with a table that had the each student listed with their name and grade for each class. Each student would have 5-7 records depending on how many classes they were taking. Note: all grades are rounded (A=95, B=85, C=75, D=65, F=55).

- Brown, C 65 World Studies
- Brown, C 75 Biology
- Brown, C 75 Dance
- Brown, C 85 Algebra
- Brown, C 85 English I
- Brown, C 85 Graphic Design
- Brown, C 95 French

I used the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gpa.ID, gpa.Student_Name, gpa.Grade, gpa.Average, gpa.Course, SUM(IF(gpa.Average=95, 1,0)) AS 'A', SUM(IF(gpa.Average=85, 1,0)) AS 'B' , SUM(IF(gpa.Average=75, 1,0)) AS 'C', SUM(IF(gpa.Average=65, 1,0)) AS 'D', SUM(IF(gpa.Average=55, 1,0)) AS 'F' FROM gpa
```

I then used the following formula to calculate the GPA.

```
<?php
  $A=$row_Recordset3['A'];
  $B=$row_Recordset3['B'];
  $C=$row_Recordset3['C'];
  $D=$row_Recordset3['D'];
  $F=$row_Recordset3['F'];
  $total=$A+$B+$C+$D+$F;

  $Aw=$row_Recordset3['A'];
  $Bw=$row_Recordset3['B'];
  $Cw=$row_Recordset3['C'];
  $Dw=$row_Recordset3['D'];
  $Fw=$row_Recordset3['F'];
  $totalw=$Aw*4+$Bw*3+$Cw*2+$Dw*1+$Fw*0;

  echo round($totalw/$total,2);
   ?>
```

It works but probably not the most computationally efficient. I now only want to echo the list of students with a GPA of 3.75 for honor roll and 4.0 for principal's scholar. They should be on the same list. Just want a way to not display under 3.75 and to echo a new column that echos honor roll or principal's scholar. I'm also hoping there is a more efficient way to calculate.

Comment: I think you should show more of your code and some example table data. Your methodology isn't very clear.

Comment: You can do this all in MySQL.  It looks like you're dumping grades to a php script, doing some strange way to count the amount of grades, then getting the total GPA and dividing it by that count then what? You should be able to just do a count(*) on the MySQL table to get the number of grades to start with.